# Posting html payload data in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular-services

I have a question related to $http post service in Angular JS.
I am currently working on CMS (Content Management System) project, where I need to send HTML data to rest api.
Currently, I am constructing payload object in angularjs controller, but when I post html data I get **unable to decode value** in developer console.
Because of this post request is not happening.
This is happening because escape character present in data.

For example:

```
var payloadData = {
    "name":"Test Document",
    "desc":"test 123",
    "content":"<div style="color:red;text-align:center;">%%header%%</div>"
}
```

[image: Developer console screenshot]

Comment: Can you show the code for your controller and http request?  You should be doing something similar to what is found here:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Comment: var payloadData = {"content_category_id":category_id+'',"content":$scope.froalaOptions.froalaEditor('html.get'),"description":description,"name":name};
                
        customHttpService.updateData(url,JSON.stringify(payloadData),helperService.postReqHeader())
            .then(function(result){
                // success          
                //Content Successfully Updated !
            }, function(err){
                // error
                //Error Occured While Updating The Content !        
            });

Answer (score 1):

use $http.post('url here',JSON.stringify(payloadData));

Comment: var payloadData = {"content_category_id":category_id+'',"content":$scope.froalaOptions.froalaEditor('html.get'),"description":description,"name":name};
                
        customHttpService.updateData(url,JSON.stringify(payloadData),helperService.postReqHeader())
            .then(function(result){
                // success          
                //Content Successfully Updated !
            }, function(err){
                // error
                //Error Occured While Updating The Content !        
            });

Comment: Hello after using JSON.stringify(payload) , still not able to use post or put http methods.

Comment: use the variable and for ex: postData = {your Payload} and pass postData to posta api

Answer (score 0):

how about using $http.post(url,payloadData,headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'})

Let us know if it works or not

Comment: if you see my code snippet i am using helperService.postR‌​eqHeader() which give me
  headers:  {
                    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+$cookies.authAppToken
                }

Comment: One interesting thing happening in this case.
I am not aware of this, but if i remove header:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'} with this, "post request is successful".
Can anybody let me know , why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

One interesting thing happening in this case.
I am not aware of this, but if i **remove** header:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'} with this, "**Post request is successful**".

Can anybody let me know , why this is happening ? 
This will helpful in understanding the problem.